# Cannot change the value of instance variable

Tags: java

I have written this piece of code to clear my doubt, I am a little confused on this.

```
class Client{
    int a=80;

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int getA()
    {
        return a;
    }

    public static void add(int b)
    {
        b=15;
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int b=10;
        System.out.println(b); //Output 10; that's Ok with me
        add(b); //Output 15; that's Ok
        System.out.println(b); // Expected output 15 but still 10
        new Client().a=56;
        System.out.println(new Client().a); //Expected output 56 but prints 80
        new Client().setA(98);
        System.out.println(new Client().a); //Expected output 98 but prints 80
        System.out.println(new Client().getA()); //Expected output 98 but prints 80
    }
}
```

Output:

```
10
15
10
80
80
80
```

Q A. In the method `add` the value of `b` is being set as `15`. Initially it was `10`. So the final value of `b` should be now `15`. It is still printing as `10`.

Q B. I have an instance variable `a` initialized with the value `80`. I create a Client object & try to change the value as you can see in the code. But the value of `a` prints the same every time. The value of `a` should change.

Comment: One way to make your misunderstanding clear: declare the `a` field as `private`.

Comment: Don't confuse yourself, with `local` and `instance` variables, here variable `b` is `local` to `main` and another variable `b` is `local` to `add` method, they both are distinct. Moreover, every object of class `Client` will have distinct copies of variable `a` as well, what you looking in output, is basically these distinct values of `a`, since, the variable `a ` is not static, therefore, it is not shared by every instance, hence every instance will have it's own copy of variable `a` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating new objects every time. Store the object reference to a variable.

```
Client client = new Client();
client.setA(56);
System.out.println(client.getA());

client.setA(98);
System.out.println(client.getA());
```

When you call `new Client()` you are creating new objects for class Client, and they are not connected to each other neither share the data.

To store the value of `b` variable and make it persistent between static method calls, declare it as a static class field.

```
class Client{
    int a=80;
    static int b;
```

and do not declare a variable with name `b` in your methods to prevent class variable shadowing by local variable.

Local variables (in your case, declared inside of your method) do not persist when your method is completed its execution.

Answer (score 2):

> So the final value of b should be now 15. It is still printing as 10.

That's a different b, as the parameter is passed by value.

```
public static void add(int b)
{
    b=15;
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

You could rewrite the code like this

```
public static void add(int anotherB)
{
    b=15;
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

and it would not compile, reinforcing that the variable in this method is different than the one declared in Main.

Rewrite it again as

```
public static void add(int anotherB)
{
    anotherB=15;
    System.out.println(anotherB);
}
```

and it will again compile, and should be clear that this is a different variable than in Main().

> But the value of a prints the same every time. The value of a should change.

Same issue.  You have two different variables, with different scope, with the same name `a`.  You have an additional issue that you keep creating new instances of Client().

Answer (score 1):

A: You are changing the value of the parameter passed in to the add() method, not the variable declared in main():

```
public static void add(int b)
{
    b=15;       // <---- This is changing the local parm
    System.out.println(b);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int b=10;  // <---- This is in the scope of main and will not be altered
    System.out.println(b); //Output 10; that's Ok with me
    add(b); //Output 15; that's Ok
    System.out.println(b); // Expected output 15 but still 10
```

B: You created an anonymous object and assigned 56 to a, the unnamed object immediately went out of scope.

```
    new Client().a=56;  // <-- changed to 56 and then gone
```

Then you create another one to print 80, and it is gone instantly too...

```
    System.out.println(new Client().a); //Expected output 56 but prints 80
```

You create another anonymous object and assign 98 to a

```
    new Client().setA(98);
```

It goes away...

You create two more nameless objects and they are initialized to 80

```
    System.out.println(new Client().a); //Expected output 98 but prints 80
    System.out.println(new Client().getA()); //Expected output 98 but prints 80
}
```

Try this instead:

```
   Client c = new Client();

   c.a=56;     // It is now 56
   System.out.println(c.a); //prints 56
   c.setA(98);
   System.out.println(c.a); //prints 98
   System.out.println(c.a); //prints 98
   System.out.println(c.getA()); //prints 98
}
```